# How to remove empty spaces from a list? Why the `if` statement does not work?

Tags: python, format

I have to write a program that takes a list of numbers and prints out a list containing the square of each number. For example, if you pass in  `[3,-1,0,2,10]`, your program should return `[9,1,0,4,100]`. I wrote the program but the output contains a list of squared numbers with spaces after commas. I did a `if` staetment, but it is not doing anything. So how do I remove the spaces? Please help!

```
def Squaring():
  List = eval(input("Please enter a list of numbers: "))
  r = []
  for i in List:
    r.append(i ** 2)

  return r

  for x in r:
    if x == ' ':
      r.remove(x)

  return r

def main():
  x = Squaring()
  print(x)

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created list must contain spaces to separate each item. But it's not the element of that particular list. You need to convert the list to a string at the final before printing. In-between for calculating the square of each number, you need to convert the number to `int`. So that you could do the mathematical operation on that number because while fetching the number, it would be fetched as string not integer. [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function will apply a function to each element in the iterable and return a list of the results. So `map(str,x)` will convert each element in the list `x` to string because you can't print integer `+` strings are the final.

```
def Squaring():
  List = eval(input(": "))
  r = []
  for i in List:
    r.append(int(i) ** 2)

  return r

def main():
  x = Squaring()
  print('[' + ','.join(map(str, x)) + ']')

main()
```

Comment: It gives me an error, saying `sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found`

Comment: You can replace `map(str, x)` with `[str(i) for i in x]` but `map` is a common part of the python language.

Comment: both do the same job... yep, op could change the last print statement to `print('[' + ','.join(str(i) for i in x) + ']')`

Comment: @achampion yep, but don't need for a list comprehension a generator expression would be enough for this case.

Answer (score 0):

The space is the default print format for list, you can print it without space by:

```
print "[" + ",".join(map(str, x)) + "]"
```

Comment: print "[" + ",".join([str(i) for i in x]) + "]"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the json module to dump a python object with more control, e.g.:

```
>>> from json import dumps
>>> print(dumps(r, separators=(',',':'))
[9,1,0,4,100]
```

Comment: How much easier do you want it? You can manually print it out as pointed out by others `print("[{}]".format(','.join(map(str, r)))`